# How to "merge" the result of two `has_many` model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to "merge" the result of two `has_many` model associations. That is, I have the following models and associations:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_comments
  has_many :unassigned_comments
end

class AssignedComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end

class UnassignedComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

I would like to implement "something" in order to run `@article.comments` and make it to return both data the `@article.assigned_comments` and `@article.unassigned_comments`.

How can I make that? There is some common practice? What about returned data and database queries?

Comment: i don't think there's a common practice. You can do it with find_by_sql and a UNION

Comment: How should appear a `find_by_sql` and `UNION` statement in my case? What can be the drawbacks?

Comment: `find_by_sql` can be called on any active record (just like `find`) and you can pass it any SQL statement eg `Article.find_by_sql("select COUNT(*) from assigned_comments")`. UNION is a standard SQL thing (google it for more). the drawbacks is that it is non-standard rails - it will not come back with a neat set of models the way an ordinary association will.

Comment: Another alternative might be to set up a polymorphic association.

Comment: How should appear `polymorphic` associations in my case? What can be the drawbacks?

Comment: google "rails polymorphic association" ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `AssignedComment` and `UnassignedComment` have the same attributes and state `assigned` can changed to `unassigned` and in reverse case, why not just add and attribute `is_signed` to the `Comment` and do something like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  scope      :assigneds,    -> { where(is_signed: true) }
  scope      :unassigneds,  -> { where(is_signed: false) }
end
```

With scope, you can do `@article.comments.assigneds` or `@article.comments.unassigneds` and of course you can simply do `@article.comments` to get all the `comments` that belong to `@article`

Comment: You should obey the law of demeter.

Comment: @Frozenna - I can not just add an attribute `is_signed` to the `Comment` because `AssignedComment` and `UnassignedComment` have *not* the same attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The accessor created by `has_many` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is basically just a wrapper for a SQL query.

You can easily write a method to combine the all of the results of the relations into an array.

```
def comments
  self.assigned_comments.to_a + self.unassigned_comments.to_a
end
```

But this has several drawbacks:

1. It always loads and initializes all of the `assigned_comments` and `unassigned_comments` into memory.
2. It doesn't have any of `ActiveRecord::Relation`'s handy methods

Depending on how similar `AssignedComment` and `UnassignedComment`'s columns are, a better solution might be to combine them into a single table and subclass.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assigned_comments, -> { where(assigned: true) }
  has_many :unassigned_comments, -> { where(assigned: false) }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  # Common functionality 
end

class AssignedComment < Comment
  default_scope { where(assigned: true) }
  before_save -> { self.assigned = true }

  # Functionality specific to AssignedComment
end

class UnassignedComment < Comment
  default_scope { where(assigned: false) }
  before_save -> { self.assigned = false }

  # Functionality specific to UnassignedComment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the answer for your question. This is a brief about STI for your case.

Single table inheritance should be considered when dealing with model classes that share much of the same functionality and data fields.

http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  scope :assigned, where(type: "AssignedComment")
  scope :unassigned, where(type: "UnassignedComment")
end

class AssignedComment < Comment

end

class UnassignedComment < Comment

end

all = @article.comments
assigned = @article.comments.assigned
unassigned = @article.comments.unassigned
```